# Jquery - Read input from Text Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form which will populate a select box "city" based on the selections of another select box "suburb".  This works for my data.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#suburb").change(function(){
        var suburb = $(this).val();//get select value
        $.ajax({
            url: "get.php",
            type: "post",
            data: { suburb: $(this).val() },
            success: function( responce ){
                $("#city").html( responce );
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
Suburb:

<select id="suburb">
    <option id="Williamstown">Williamstown</option>
    <option id="Altona">altona</option>
    <option id="Newport">newport</option>
 </select> 
 <select id="city"></select>
```

Instead of having the `<select id="suburb">` box I would like to make it a text input
`<input type="text" name="suburb">` and use the value in the input text field to populate the city select box.

I have tried changing it to

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#suburb").keyup(function(){
        var suburb = $("#suburb").val(); //get select value
        $.ajax({
             url: "get.php",
             type: "post",
             data: { suburb: $("#suburb").val() },
             success: function( responce ){
                  $("#city").html( responce );
             }
        });
    });
});
</script>
Suburb:

 <input type="text" name="suburb">
 <select id="city"></select>
```

But this doesn't return anything.  Im sure Im not reading the input in the "suburb" field correctly

Comment: If you add `console.log(suburb); ` between the `var` and `$.ajax` lines, what do you see in the console?

Comment: What should happen if the suburb name the user enters isn't available in the select box?

Comment: Please post the PHP code in `get.php` that answers the ajax requests.

Comment: Felix's answer below works for me

Comment: Do you realize that the code initializes `var suburb = ...` but never uses it?  Felix shows how to use it so the code doesn't repeat itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you give your `input` name attribute, you can target it by name instead of `id`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=suburb]').keyup(function () {
        var suburb = $(this).val(); //get select value
        $.ajax({
            url: "get.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                suburb: suburb
            },
            success: function (responce) {
                $("#city").html(responce);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#suburb").keyup(function()
    {
    var suburb = $("input[name=suburb]").val();//get select value
    $.ajax(
    {
    url:"get.php",
    type:"post",
    data:{suburb:$("input[name=suburb]").val()},
    success:function(responce)
    {
    $("#city").html(responce);
    }
    });
    });
    });
    </script>

This is what I'm using, and still not returning anything

Comment: ok thanks this works.. I have to wait 5 minutes to accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#suburb").blur(function()
   {
     var suburb = $("#suburb").val();//get select value
     $.ajax(
     {
     url:"get.php",
     type:"post",
     data:{suburb:$("#suburb").val()},
     success:function(responce)
    { $("#city").html(responce);}
    });
    });
  });
</script>
Suburb:

<input type="text" name="suburb">
<select id="city"></select>
```